# how not to render a component in react when state change

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple Todo application.

The array of tasks sits in the APP component
And it changes accordingly several times: by adding and editing.
When I edit the task, the array changes, which re-runs the APP and all the code inside it.
I would like to avoid this and not render the APP. It's unnecessary because I'm already rendering the list that shows my tasks.

What is the best approach I should take?

**app**

```
export default function App() {

  const [todoArr, setTodoArr] = useState(getTasksFromLs())

....
```

**Where I edit the task in the Task component**

```
   const editTask = (e, id) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        setTodoArr(todoArr.map((task) => task.id !== id ?
            task
            :
            { ...task, texst: inpValue }
        ))

        setedit(prev => !prev)
        let LS_task = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(id))
        LS_task.texst = inpValue
        localStorage.setItem(id, JSON.stringify(LS_task))
    }
```

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the issue. Do you mean that `setedit` updates some local state piece and that's why you'd like to avoid setting `todoArr` which sits in the top level?

Comment: no  setTodoArr Updater sharpens the array, which causes the state of the array to be updated, which causes APP re-render

Comment: The simple answer is that if you need some value to remain the same within the lifecycle of the component, you can use [`useRef`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref). This hook will store a value and unlike `useState`, won't cause a re-render when changed.

Comment: But i'm trying to understand why this is the desired behavior. It usually points to a weird code structure.

Comment: I need the APP component not to re-render when a certain state within it has changed.

My relationship tree goes like this:
1) APP
2)LIST,FORM are direct children of APP
3) TASK is a direct child of LIST

Comment: I know the use of USEREF to create focus on a certain input,
But I don't know a usage like you mentioned, do you have a piece of code for an example?

Comment: `useRef` is often used to store elements like in the use-case you've mentioned, but it can also be used to store pretty much any other value. Here's an example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-typescript-forked-vmvw32?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set state back to that where it already have. Just an example given below-

```
import React, {useState} from "react";

const App = ()=>{
const [stateChange, setStateChage] = useState("false")
const [changeText, setChangeText] = useState("")
const
const handleClick(e)=>{
setStateChange("true");
setChangeText(e.target.value);
setStateChange("false");
}

return(
<div>
<input type="text" onChange={setChangeText(e.target.value)} placeholder="text"></input>
<span>{changeText}</span>
<input type="submit" onclick="()=>handleClick()">Submit</submit>
</div>
)

}
```

As seen in the above I just trying to show you example that you can use a function that change state before exit.

If you still got error just share an sandbox link with code. I try to help you.